# Where should PHP file of custom widget be in?

Tags: craft3, dashboard-widgets

I would like to develop my custom widget as this document in Craft 3.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/widget-types.html#registering-custom-widget-types

However, it does not tell me where the PHP file should be in. I suppose it is not under `vender/craftcms`, because it would be deleted by Craft update. I wonder if you could tell where.

Answer (score 1):

If it were my project, I would probably put the PHP file in `modules`

Here's some more info https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/ and here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html

Comment: Additional resources include the [Business Logic module template](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-businesslogic), and the [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io) plugin/module generator.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to read the documents when I continue to develop it.